# Stop character from falling over in Corona

Tags: lua, rotation, coronasdk, sprite

I have a sprite character (dynamic physics object), walking along a sloped platform (static physics object). However, the character sometimes '*wobbles*' or falls over. I want to stop this.

I don't want to use `sprite.isFixedRotation` as this keeps the sprite always standing straight. I would like the character to rotate based on the incline of the slope.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve. How can it fall over if it is a static physics object? Perhaps some images would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could give your object a bit of a base by creating a custom shape.

Rob